# printf is somehow converting binary to decimal

Tags: c, printf

Newbie question: why can't I get `printf` to output the binary number as it is, instead of converting it?

```
int gpa = 01011001;
printf("pure: %i \n", gpa);
```

gives the output: 266753

How can I get it to output 01011001 or just 1011001?

Comment: "*or just 1011001?*" --> Use `int gpa = 1011001;`. Since the integer literal in `int gpa = 01011001;` begins with 0, it is considered as an octal number.

Comment: There are two misunderstandings as it seems: 1) in C you cannot directly initialize an `int` with a literal in binary format (base-2)  (as mentioned: leading `0` interprets literal as octal number). 2) an `int` holds a _number_, it is neither binary, decimal, octal or whatever. If you want to display such number you have to decide in which base the string representation should be: `printf("%i")` displays a number in decimal format.

Comment: The fact that you're using only 1s and 0s in that value doesn't make it binary "in the eyes of the compiler" (did you really expect the compiler to be able to tell what base you're using according to the digits???).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0` preceding an integer literal is hold for octa-decimal number. Decimal equivalent of `01011001` is `266753`. Remove that preceding `0` to print as it is.

Comment: I think OP wants to initialize `gpa` with a binary constant (base-2) and this is not possible directly in C. `1011001` would be used as decimal literal of course.

Comment: I think OP expects the compiler to determine the base of the number according to its digits, to calculate the value of the number on that base, and to assign that value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support binary constants (although individual compilers may as an extension).

You could use hexadecimal notation instead:

```
int gpa = 0x59; // 01011001 binary
printf( " pure: %02x\n", gpa );
```

If you want to display the value in binary format, you'll have to roll your own output function.